# Atlasboard packaging and deployment

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, atlasboard

I'm trying to package and deploy my Atlasboard dashboard via IBM BlueMix.

How do I package atlasboard and include the global dependencies as local?

How do I start the board as the usual "atlasboard start" won't work any more as there is no global dependency for this?

Answer (score 4):

After packing dependencies as local rather than global discovered that bluemix requires node applications to start on a specific port which is specified in an envrionment variable, my solution was to add this to package.json:

```
"dependencies":{
    "atlasboard": "^0.13.0"
},
"scripts":{
    "start":"node start"
}
```

And this to start.js:

```
var atlasboard = require('atlasboard');

var port = process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000

atlasboard({port: port}, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
});
```

Comment: That's correct. Atlasboard 1.0 will include a start.js script so you don't need to workaround this problem anymore.